# Why are there two different definitions for independent increments?

Tags: probability-theory, independence

Let $\{X(t)\}_{t \in \mathcal{T}}$ be a real valued stochastic process. Why are there the following two different definitions for independent increments?

1. $X$ has independent increments, if for all $t_0<t_1 \dots < t_n \in \mathcal{T}, n \in \mathbb{N}, \; X(t_n)-X(t_{n-1}),\dots, X(t_1)-X(t_0),X(t_0)$ are independent.
2. $X$ has independent increments, if for all $t_1< \dots < t_n \in \mathcal{T}, n \in \mathbb{N}, \; X(t_n)-X(t_{n-1}),\dots, X(t_2)-X(t_1)$ are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You often have that $X_0=0$, or constant. In that case, by considering $t_0=0$, the two definitions are equivalent. In the general case they need not be, and I think the second definition prevails, as suggested by the  [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_increments#:%7E:text=In%20probability%20theory%2C%20independent%20increments,definition%2C%20which%20underlines%20their%20importance.).